# Pitfalls in prototype database design (for performance viability testing)

Tags: performance, oracle, database-design, prototype

Following on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020270/efficiency-of-hibernates-table-per-subclass-inheritance-strategy), I'm looking to run some performance tests on various potential schema representations of an object model.  However, the catch is that while the model is conceptually complete, it's not actually finalised yet - and so the exact number of tables, and numbers/types of attributes in each table aren't definite.

From my (possibly naive) perspective it seems like it should be possible to put together a *representative* prototype model for each approach, and test the performance of each of these to determine which is the fastest approach for each case.

And that's where the question comes in.  I'm aware that the performance characteristics of databases can be very non-intuitive, such that a small (even "trivial") change can lead to an order of magnitude difference.  Thus I'm wondering what common pitfalls there might be when setting up a dummy table structure and populating it with dummy data.  Since the environment is likely to make a massive difference here, the target is Oracle 10.2.0.3.0 running on RHEL 3.

(In particular, I'm looking for examples such as "make sure that one of your tables has a much more selective index than the other"; "make sure you have more than *x* rows/columns because below this you won't hit page faults and the performance will be different"; "ensure you test with the DATETIME datatype if you're going to use it because it will change the query plan greatly", and so on.  I tried Google, expecting there would be lots of pages/blog posts on best practices in this area, but couldn't find the trees for the wood (lots of pages about tuning performance of an existing DB instead).)

As a note, I'm willing to accept an answer along the lines of "it's not feasible to perform a test like this with any degree of confidence in the transitivity of the result", if that is indeed the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do to position yourself to meet performance objectives.  I think they happen in this order:

1. be aware of architectures, best practices and patterns
2. be aware of how the database works
3. spot-test performance to get additional precision or determine impact of wacky design areas

More on each:

1. Architectures, best practices and patterns:  one of the most common reasons for reporting databases to fail to perform is that those who build them are completely unfamiliar with the reporting domain.  They may be experts on the transactional database domain - but the techniques from that domain do not translate to the warehouse/reporting domain.   So, you need to know your domain well - and if you do you'll be able to quickly identify an appropriate approach that will work almost always - and that you can tweak from there.
2. How the database works:  you need to understand in general what options the optimizer/planner has for your queries.   What's the impact to different statements of adding indexes?  What's the impact of indexing a 256 byte varchar?  Will reporting queries even use your indexes?  etc
3. Now that you've got the right approach, and generally understand how 90% of your model will perform - you're often done forecasting performance with most small to medium size databases.  If you've got a huge one, there's a ton at stake, you've got to get more precise (might need to order more hardware), or have a few wacky spots in the design - then focus your tests on just this.  Generate reasonable test data - and (important) stats that you'd see in production.  And look to see what the database will do with that data.  Unless you've got real data and real prod-sized servers you'll still have to extrapolate - but you should at least be able to get reasonably close.

Comment: All three answers are good and come to broadly the same conclusion; I've accepted this one mainly through eenie-meenie-minie-mo.

Answer (score 1):

Running performance tests against various putative implementation of a conceptual model is not naive so much as heroically forward thinking.  Alas I suspect it will be a waste of your time.

Let's take one example: data.  Presumably you are intending to generate random data to populate your tables.  That might give you some feeling for how well a query might perform with large volumes.  But often performance problems are a product of skew in the data; a random set of data will give you an averaged distribution of values.

Another example: code. Most performance problems are due to badly written SQL, especially inappropriate joins.  You might be able to apply an index to tune an individual for `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE blah` but that isn't going to help you forestall badly written queries.

The truism about premature optimization applies to databases as well as algorithms.  The most important thing is to get the data model complete and correct.  If you manage that you are already ahead of the game.

**edit**

Having read the question which you linked to I more clearly understand where you are coming from.    I have a little experience of this Hibernate mapping problem from the database designer perspective.   Taking the example you give at the end of the page ...

`Animal` > `Vertebrate` > `Mammal` > `Carnivore` > `Canine` > `Dog type` hierarchy,

... the key thing is to instantiate objects as far down the chain as possible.  Instantiating a column of `Animals` will perform much slower than instantiating separate collections of `Dogs`, `Cats`, etc. (presuming you have tables for all or some of those sub-types).

This is more of an application design issue than a database one.  What will make a difference is whether you only build tables at the concrete level (CATS, DOGS) or whether you replicate the hierarchy in tables (ANIMALS, VERTEBRATES, etc).  Unfortunately there are no simple answers here.  For instance, you have to consider not just the performance of data retrieval but also how Hibernate will handle inserts and updates: a design which performs well for queries might be a real nightmare when it comes to persisting data.  Also relational integrity has an impact: if you have some entity which applies to all `Mammals`, it is comforting to be able to enforce a foreign key against a MAMMALS table.

Comment: Thanks for a well thought-out answer.  The representativity of data is a real concern and I think this may be insurmountable as you seem to agree with.  As it happens I'm not too worried about poorly-written SQL in the app - as per my previous question (linked) I want to try various table layouts in order to determine which will allow the most performant SQL.  Since this will ultimately be issued by Hibernate and is tweakable if required I'm not too worried about other developers writing poor queries (which might otherwise be a real concern).

Comment: (response to edit): I agree entirely that fetching the most specific type is the way forward, and this is almost always possible when doing a manual HQL query to get an Animal instance itself.  However, if I'm using Hibernate to fetch, let's say, a `Cage` (which has an Animal field with one-to-one mapping) then the query to look this up from an ID will have to be on the top-level type. 

I appreciate your last paragraph too; I'm aware of the SQL that will be used in various CRUD operations and would be testing all of them to identify the best tradeoff for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Performance problems with databases do not scale linearly with data volume.  A database with a million rows in it might show one hotspot, while a similar database with a billion rows in it might reveal an entirely different hotspot.  Beware of tests conducted with sample data.

You need good sound database design practices in order to keep your design simple and sound.  Worry about whether your database meets the data requirements, and whether your model is relevant, complete, correct and relational (provided you're building a relational database) before you even start worrying about speed.

Then, once you've got something that's simple, sound, and correct, start worrying about speed.  You'd be amazed at how much you can speed things up by just tweaking the physical features of your database, without changing any app code.  To do this, you need to learn a lot about your particular DBMS.

They never said database development would be easy.  They just said it would be this much fun!