# Table per subclass inheritance relationship: How to query against the Parent class without loading any subclass ??? (Hibernate)

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, inheritance, hql

Suppose a **Table per subclass inheritance relationship** which can be described bellow (From wikibooks.org - see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined.2C_Multiple_Table_Inheritance))

Notice Parent class **is not abstract**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Project {

    @Id
    private long id;

    // Other properties

}

@Entity
@Table(name="LARGEPROJECT")
public class LargeProject extends Project {

    private BigDecimal budget;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="SMALLPROJECT")
public class SmallProject extends Project {

}
```

**I have a scenario** where **i just need to retrieve the Parent class**. Because of performance issues, What should i do **to run a HQL query** in order to retrieve the Parent class and **just** the Parent class without loading any subclass ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A workaround is described below:

Define your `Parent` class as *MappedSuperClass*. Let's suppose the parent class is mapped To `PARENT_TABLE`

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class AbstractParent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(table="PARENT_TABLE")        
    private String someProperty;

    // getter's and setter's

}
```

For each subclass, extend the `AbstractParent` class and define its *SecondaryTable*. Any persistent field defined in the parent class will be mapped to the table defined by *SecondaryTable*. And finally, use AttributeOverrides if needed

```
@Entity
@SecondaryTable("PARENT_TABLE")
public class Child extends AbstractParent {

    private String childField;

    public String getChildProperty() {
        return childField;
    }

}
```

And define another Entity with the purpose of retrieving just the parent class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT_TABLE")
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="someProperty", column=@Column(name="someProperty"))
})
public class Parent extends AbstractParent {}
```

Nothing else. See as shown above i have used just JPA specific annotations

Comment: Good idea, but I was wondering if this can be achieved by using InheritanceType.JOINED? I have read that following annoatation can be used on root entity @Polymorphism(type = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT). I have tried that with no luck however.

Comment: I have the same problem and using Hibernate 4.3.7 .. by using InheritanceType.JOINED want to retrieve data only from the parent class... @svlada so do you have any solution for that?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** It appears the first option doesn't work as I thought.

#### First option:

Specify the class in the where clause:

```
select p from Project p where p.class = Project
```

#### Second option:

Use explicit polymorphism that you can set using Hibernate's [`@Entity`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-entity) annotation:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(polymorphism = PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Project {

    @Id
    private long id;
    ...
}
```

This is what Hibernate Core documentation writes about [explicit polymorphism](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-declaration-class):

> Implicit polymorphism means that
>   instances of the class will be
>   returned by a query that names any
>   superclass or implemented interface or
>   class, and that instances of any
>   subclass of the class will be returned
>   by a query that names the class
>   itself. Explicit polymorphism means
>   that class instances will be returned
>   only by queries that explicitly name
>   that class.

#### See also

- [How to get only super class in table-per-subclass strategy?](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=958277)

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Thank you for your reply but The first approach shown by yourself "left inner join" **all of subclasses** (You can test if you want). And i just need to retrieve **just** The Parent class - select ... from Project where p.id = :id without no "left inner join" with any subclass

Comment: @Arthur I thought I tested this but I believe you. Will take a second look later in the day...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way to get just the superclass, you just need to use the native query from JPA, in my case I'm using JPA Repositories it would be something like that:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM project", nativeQuery = true)
List<Resource> findAllProject();
```

The flag nativeQuery as true allow running the native SQL on database.

If you are using Entity Manager check this out: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/