# Hibernate Inheritance problem

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.0 . I am facing an issue  in using joined sub class.

Here is a small example

I have an Animal super class, and i have 2 sub classses Dog and Cat.
I am jusing joined sub class for defining this relationship.

when i do

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from Animal");
```

it is fetching the objects of animal,dog and cat.

This is creating a problems as the fetching time is more.

Any solution for the same.

Comment: You mean you only want to return `Animal` entities, not `Dog` or `Cat`?

Comment: Exactly what is your question? I don't get it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table per subclass inheritance relationship: How to query against the Parent class without loading any subclass ??? (Hibernate)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700680/table-per-subclass-inheritance-relationship-how-to-query-against-the-parent-clas)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want the Animal instances, not their subclasses?

That's a little tricky to do in JPA, as cats are also animals, hence they are returned.

You have to exclude them manually from the query, like this:

```
from Animal a 
     where a.id not in (select c.id from Cat c)
       and a.id not in (select d.id from Dog d)
```

(As you have this problem, maybe polymorphism isn't perfect solution in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can switch-off the implicit polymorphism for this class by setting `polymorphism="explicit"` in the xml mapping, or use the hibernate annotation `@Entity(polymorphism=PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)`