# Hibernate: Persist class as Interface

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

We have a class `Phone` which uses  `Role`s, ie.

```
@Entity
public class Phone{
  @Id...
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name="role_id")
  private IRole role;
  ...
```

and the interface

```
public interface IRole extends Serializable {
    public abstract Integer getId();
    ...
```

So when I try to persist `Phone` in my package the `IRole` isn't any longer abstract it is already a concrete entity. The reason why I cannot use the concrete class directly is that we implemented the `Role`  differently in projects.

When I try to start Hibernate I get an Exception:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [role_id
] in table [phone]; found [int4 (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bytea (Types#VARBINARY)]
```

I think the `IRole` causes the problem. It should store the `id` of the `Role` - which is available in all our implementations. How to tell Hibernate that it should use type `Integer` instead of some `interface` interpolation?

Looking for a solution which would work in `Postgres` as well in `MariaDB`.

Comment: Change `role`  from `IRole` to `Integer` in your `Phone` class and then fix the references.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to keep integrity of the objects and not start handling my own objects.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827494/inherited-abstract-class-with-jpa-hibernate. Its for abstract class not for interfaces though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement an [attribute converter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-jpa-convert) for each your particular implementation of `IRole` interface and then use them.

```java
  @Convert(converter=RoleA.class)
  @Column(name="role_id_a")
  private IRole roleA;

  @Convert(converter=RoleB.class)
  @Column(name="role_id_b")
  private IRole roleB;
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this coud be a valid approach. I'll check it. Thx for the hint.