# abstract entity class mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, abstract-class

I have an abstract superclass entity which is the following:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Notification {
  @id
  private int id;
  private Stringname;

        public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Then, I have two class which extends this abstract class

```
@Entity
public class smsNotifcation extends Notification {

  @id
  private String name;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

}


@Entity
public class emailNotifcation extends Notification {

  @id
  private String name;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

When I use `persistence.xml` to auto-create the tables in the `PostgreSQL`, it only creates the table for the `Notification class`. I am unable to understand why it wont create tables for the other two. If it is not supposed to create them, then how would I map the information. By mapping information, I meant that how will the `name` attribute from `Notification` class know that to which class this name belongs to i.e the name in abstract class's database belongs to `smsNotification` or `emailNotification`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inherited abstract class with JPA (+Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827494/inherited-abstract-class-with-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: @Mark unfortunately, no. I am confused with that given examples as it has similar names init. if possible you can explain to me in this possible scenerio, Thank you.