# Polymorphic persistence with hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying all day to persist an entity "resultatRAT"

**ResultatRAT.class**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "resultat_rat")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@DiscriminatorValue("REMBOURSEMENT_TOTAL")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ResultatRAT extends Resultat implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "montant_remboursement", nullable = false)
    private Float montantRemboursement;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pre_solde_dispo", nullable = false)
    private Float preSoldeDispo;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "post_solde_dispo", nullable = false)
    private Float postSoldeDispo;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "duree_restante", nullable = false)
    private Integer dureeRestante;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pre_echeance", nullable = false)
    private Float preEcheance;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "post_echeance", nullable = false)
    private Float postEcheance;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "capital_amorti", nullable = false)
    private Float capitalAmorti;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "capital_restant_du", nullable = false)
    private Float capitalRestantDu;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "mnt_penalite_ht", nullable = false)
    private Float mntPenaliteHT;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "taxe_penalite_ht", nullable = false)
    private Float taxePenaliteHT;

// Getters and setter omitted for brevity
}
```

this is the mother class "Resultat"

**Resultat.class**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "resultat")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "typeSimulation", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME
    , property = "typeSimulation")
@JsonSubTypes(
    {
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResultatRAP.class, name = "REMBOURSEMENT_PARTIEL"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ResultatRAT.class, name = "REMBOURSEMENT_TOTAL"),
    }
)
public abstract class Resultat implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "resultat", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Simulation simulation;

    @Column(name = "typeSimulation", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TypeSimulation typeSimulation; 
// Getters and setter omitted for brevity
}
```

but each attempt have been a failure , the post method is pretty standard

```java
 @PostMapping("/resultats")
    public Resultat createResultat(@RequestBody Resultat resultat) throws URISyntaxException {
        if (resultat.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new resultat cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        Resultat result = resultatRepository.save(resultat);
        return result;
    }
```

and this is my JSON object

```json
   {
            "typeSimulation":"REMBOURSEMENT_TOTAL",
            "montantRemboursement":22.0,
            "preSoldeDispo":2222.0,
            "postSoldeDispo":2.0,
            "dureeRestante":221,
            "preEcheance":341.0,
            "postEcheance":53.0,
            "capitalAmorti":12345.0,
            "capitalRestantDu":235.0,
            "mntPenaliteHT":231.0,
            "taxePenaliteHT":231.0
 }
```

each time I request my object to be persisted I get this error

> Invalid value "1" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200]
> [image: Logstash]

Any idea on how to solve this problem? Thank you very much

Comment: is it really necessary to establish  `Resultat` with `@Entity` annotation? In my opinion it could be marked as `@MappedSuperclass` only. Apparently hibernate is trying to build the `resultat` table and add a new record to it.

Comment: Yes, I find it necessary, since I need it for `@OneToOne` relationships, and `Resultat`  can only be one of  `Resultat` child types.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe, please believe that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827546/11868833

Comment: Yes looks like I have no choice but to use `MappedSupperClass`,thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Yoy have `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) ` and `@Discriminator...`, why is that?

Comment: I discovered later , that i don't need `@Discriminator..` when using joined strategy , but it doesn't affect the outcome